# Pointer to a typedef in a function?

Tags: c

I'm completely new to C and coding in general, please be patient with me. I want to learn how to use pointers with a typedef structure inside of a function. As far as I know my code isn't wrong and there's no warnings/errors, anything could help, thank you

```
typedef struct
{
     double year, month, day;
} Date;

void changedate(Date red)
{
     Date* blue = &red;
     blue->year = 2022;
     blue->month = 5;
     blue->day = 7;
}

int main(void)
{
     Date pee = {2002, 5, 17};
     printf("This is the date: %.0lf/%.0lf/%.0lf\n", pee.year, pee.month, pee.day);
     changedate(pee);
     printf("This is the date: %.0lf/%.0lf/%.0lf  ", pee.year, pee.month, pee.day);

     keypress();
     return 0;
}
```

So yeah, I'm trying to get it to store the new date values and print it out, but it doesn't seem to work. Anything could help

Comment: When you pass an object by value (like this: `(Date red)`) the function changedate will receive a copy. So the changes will not affect the `pee` object you passed into it.

Comment: And `Date* blue = &red;` doesn't change anything, you can just work with `red` directly. The solution is to make the function parameter a pointer.

Comment: When you pass `pee` to the `changedate()` function through the parameter `Date red`, the parameter is a local-copy of `pee` and any changes you make to `red` or `blue` in the function are lost when the function returns. Instead you pass a pointer to `pee`., e.g. `changedate(&pee)` and change your function to `void changedate (Date *red)`. Understand, the function still receives a Copy-Of-The-Pointer, but the copy holds the same address as its value. So you can change the value at that address and it will be reflected in `main()` on return.

Comment: `int foo = 4; changefoo(foo); printf("foo is %d\n", foo);` The print will **always** print `4` no matter what happens inside `changefoo()` -- `changefoo()` receives a **copy** of the actual object. Same thing happens with your `changedate()` function.

Answer (score 2):

###### Some Points:

- `unsigned int` will do the job, there's no need for `double` data type
- **You need to pass the address to the function, or return the changed `Date`, and then assign it to `pee`**
- `keypress()` is not a standard function
- `pee` isn't a good word for a variable

###### Final Code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    unsigned int year, month, day;
} Date;

void changedate(Date *red) {
    red->year = 2022;
    red->month = 5;
    red->day = 7;
}

int main(void) {
    Date red = {2002, 5, 17};
    printf("This is the date: %u/%u/%u\n", red.year, red.month, red.day);
    changedate(&red);
    printf("This is the date: %u/%u/%u\n", red.year, red.month, red.day);
    return 0;
}
```

###### Another Approach

```c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    unsigned int year, month, day;
} Date;

Date changedate(Date red) {
    red.year = 2022;
    red.month = 5;
    red.day = 7;
    return red;
}

int main(void) {
    Date red = {2002, 5, 17};
    printf("This is the date: %u/%u/%u\n", red.year, red.month, red.day);
    red = changedate(red);
    printf("This is the date: %u/%u/%u\n", red.year, red.month, red.day);
    return 0;
}
```